# Tree Sapling Generator - How to change default insert location from world origin to 3D cursor

Tags: add-on, 3d-cursor

I'm trying to change to insertion or spawn location for the tree (or curve) from the default world origin to a new desired 3D cursor location.  I can't find where to make this change.

Thanks,
Darren

Comment: Just move the 3D cursor with Shift Right-click to where you want to create the tree, create it, and Shift-C to move the cursor back to the world origin. You can use the normal transform keys to move the tree where you want it later.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The Sapling Tree Generator will not work with the typical 3D-Cursor behavior you are suggesting. I can create any other geo and locate it to a custom 3D-Cursor location. Just not working the same with this add-on. The other problem is you can't go back and modify the tree with the native Sapling tree generator tools after placement. I can move the tree after creation, but then I can't modify it with the native tools.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The Sapling Tree Generator will not work with the typical 3D-Cursor behavior you are suggesting. I can create any other geo and locate it to a custom 3D-Cursor location. Just not working the same with this add-on. The other problem is you can't go back and modify the tree with the native Sapling tree generator tools after placement. I can move the tree after creation, but then I can't modify it with the native tools.  Thx again

Comment: Hmm... That I didn't realise! It's a very long time since I used that addon. If it hadn't been available for such a long time I'd have considered that to be a bug! I did realise that it couldn't be modified after being moved though which is why I was so surprised to hear that it wasn't created wherever you placed the cursor.